# Select first duplicate in aliased field SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that uses a CASE .. WHEN statement that creates an aliased field based upon the values of other fields.

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  CASE 
    WHEN LEN(LastName) = 0 THEN FirstName
  END AS DisplayName
FROM MyTable
```

The resultant SELECT statement often contains "duplicates" for the alias `DisplayName`. I understand they are not truly duplicates because the ID field is unique. How do I go about obtaining a DISTINCT list of `DisplayName` if I don't care which ID is associated with it? I cannot use the `DisplayName` alias in a `GROUP BY` statement because of the order of Logical Operator Precedence.

UPDATE - I should have mentioned that I do need to get the ID back, however, as long as the ID is associated with one of the duplicates (first, last, etc ..)

Comment: Why are you selecting the ID if you don't care about it?

Comment: I still need to ID to pass back to the UI. As long as the ID is one of the IDs associated with a "duplicate".

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   MAX(ID) [ID],
   DisplayName
FROM (
    SELECT 
      ID,
      CASE 
        WHEN LEN(LastName) = 0 THEN FirstName
      END AS DisplayName
    FROM MyTable
) a
GROUP BY DisplayName
```

Comment: Because a GROUP BY is evaluated before the SELECT clause an alias cannot be used in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the logic is that you want the last name, if available, otherwise the first name.  This is not exactly what your query does.

Just use aggregation with a `case` statement:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as id
       (CASE WHEN LEN(LastName) = 0 THEN FirstName ELSE LastName END) AS DisplayName
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN LEN(LastName) = 0 THEN FirstName ELSE LastName END);
```

If you stored empty values as `NULL` instead of `''`, this would be more simply written as:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as id
       COALESCE(LastName, FirstName) AS DisplayName
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COALESCE(LastName, FirstName) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (
SELECT 
 ID,
 CASE 
  WHEN LEN(LastName) = 0 THEN FirstName
  END AS DisplayName
  FROM MyTable)
select distinct id, displayname from x
```

If you prefer using `cte` this is one way to do it.

Comment: This doesn't return id.

Comment: that wasn't in the requirement earlier

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `GROUP BY` an alias name then you'll need to use nested queries like so.

```
SELECT MAX(t.ID), t.DisplayName FROM (
SELECT 
  ID,
  CASE WHEN LEN(LastName) = 0 THEN FirstName END AS 'DisplayName'
FROM MyTable) as t
GROUP BY t.DisplayName
```

Since you have to return an ID and you don't care which ID you return, just return the `MAX` one. As long as you have a function that aggregates your ID like `MAX` or `MIN` you can group by DisplayName.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Row_Number() OVER() and just choose the first instance.  I'm not sure if you meant to exclude an ELSE statement in your CASE WHEN, but it would either return the first name, if last name has a length of 0, or NULL otherwise.

```
SELECT ID,DisplayName
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY CASE 
      WHEN LEN(LastName) = 0 THEN FirstName
    END

    ORDER BY CASE 
      WHEN LEN(LastName) = 0 THEN FirstName
    END
    ) RowID,
    ID,
    CASE 
      WHEN LEN(LastName) = 0 THEN FirstName
    END AS DisplayName
  FROM MyTable
 ) a
 WHERE RowID = 1
```